# How to add default value in json object array?

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON object array as shown below. The following o/p is achieved by doing `echo '<pre>'; print_r($data->abc_def_ghi); echo '</pre>';`

```
[abc_def_ghi] => Array
    (
        [0] => no
        [1] => yes
        [2] => yes
        [3] => nada
        [4] => nada
        [5] => nada
    )
```

In the JSON object array above, I want to add the default value nada for all the values above.  What I want to achieve is this on the 1st day of every month.

```
[abc_def_ghi] => Array
    (
        [0] => nada
        [1] => nada
        [2] => nada
        [3] => nada
        [4] => nada
        [5] => nada
    )
```

This is what I have tried but it is deleting the json object array from the whole json.

```
$isSet = true;
if((date('j') == 1) && $isSet) 
{
    unset($data->abc_def_ghi);
     $isSet=false;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that so all the default values are present in the json object array when 
it 1st day of every month.

Comment: `$data->abc_def_ghi = array_fill(0, count($data->abc_def_ghi), default_value);`

Comment: @splash58 it worked, thanks for the help. I am wondering if there is any way I can apply the same logic at particular day and time in php. This is what I have tried: `$isSet = true; if((date('j') == 1) && (date('h:i:s')=="12:00:00")) && $isSet) { unset($data->abc_def_ghi); $isSet=false; }`

Comment: @splash58 Can I run a function in php at particular time of the day just one ?

Comment: To run a function at particular time  **just one**, you need any flag to check that function was run - a record in DB, any log file, ets.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I am wondering how I can implement that logic. Any hint will be highly appreciated